# WebView shouldOverrideUrlLoading Android for imageView

Tags: android, webview

I'm using the following code to load an image in a volley NetworkedImageView and it works well. But I have one issue I can't seem to resolve. When the user presses the back button from ImageView, I don't want the image also loaded in the WebView

When I return back to my WebView activity the image is loaded there as well.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        //NEED TO NOT Load URL in Webview
        if (url.toLowerCase().contains(".jpg")) {
            startImageView(url);
        } else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

This calls the following code to start my ImageView Activity

```
public void startImageView(String url) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,
        ImageViewActivity.class);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Short of calling webView.goBack() in onResume, which I think is rather inelegant, but functional. Is there a way to not have the webView also load the image?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

I had to override the OnPageStarted method of WebViewClient as follows to keep it from loading the image to start with.

```
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
        if(url.toLowerCase().contains(".jpg")){
            view.stopLoading();
        }
    }
```